# Common c# idioms including coalesce ?? operator

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

Everyone knows at least two common c# idioms including coalesce operator:

a singleton one:

```
return _staticField = _staticField ?? new SingletonConstructor();
```

and a chain one:

```
notNullableResult = nullable1 ?? nullable2 ?? nullable3 ?? default(someType);
```

it's readable, consistent, worth using and recognizable in code.

But, unfortunately, this is all. Sometimes it will need expanding or change. Sometimes i use them when i see a particular case - and always i hesitate to use it because i dont know if any other programmer will really read it easy.

Do you know any others? I would love to have more specific usages: e.g. Asp.net, EF, LINQ, anything - where coalesce is not only acceptable but remarkable.

Comment: It seems to me that all uses of the null coalescing operator are just special cases of your "chain one".

Comment: still, all the cases are more or less special or general. for me, art of programming is to balance and feel the difference.

coalesce is a special case of 'if' statement, isn't it? and switch - case is a special, so what - to remove them?

Comment: That's not how you implement a lazily-instantiated singleton.  Even if you just left out a `lock` block for the sake of brevity in this question, it still only serves to obfuscate the code.

Comment: i don't need always a lazy singleton:) life is sad sometimes

Comment: you mean thread safe, not lazy, i guess?

Comment: The singleton code you posted is clearly a lazy initializer; and yes, the lack of thread-safety is indeed what I was hinting at.

Answer (score 6):

For me, where it translates to SQL is good enough by itself:

```
from a in DB.Table
select new {
             a.Id,
             Val = a.One ?? a.Two ??a.Three
           }
```

This resulting in `COALSCE` on the database side makes for **tremendously** cleaner SQL in most cases, there just isn't any great alternative.  We're using Oracle, I'd rather not read though `Nvl(Nvl(Nvl(Nvl(` nesting thank you...I'll take my `COALSCE` and run with it.

I also use it for properties like this, just personal taste I guess:

```
private string _str;
public string Str { 
  get { return _str ?? (_str = LoaderThingyMethod()); } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason that the null-coalescing operator has been introduced in C# 2.0 was to have an way to assign default values to [nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) and thus easily convert a nullable type into a non-nullable type. Without `??` any conversion would require a lengthy `if` statement. The following quote is taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

> A nullable type can contain a value,
>   or it can be undefined. The ??
>   operator defines the default value to
>   be returned when a nullable type is
>   assigned to a non-nullable type. If
>   you try to assign a nullable value
>   type to a non-nullable value type
>   without using the ?? operator, you
>   will generate a compile-time error. If
>   you use a cast, and the nullable value
>   type is currently undefined, an
>   InvalidOperationException exception
>   will be thrown.

You might consider the following simplification "remarkable":

```
int? x = null;
int y = x ?? -1;
```

Instead of

```
int? x = null;
int y = -1;

if (x.HasValue)
{
    y = x.Value;
}
```

Comment: yes, i should have specified that a chain is usually about nullables. thank you.

Comment: The null coalescing operator was actually introduced in C# 2.0, not 3.0 (same as nullable types)